# D3 and GeoJSON - strange lines?

Tags: d3.js, geojson

Why is my GeoJSON rendered like this with D3 given below code? (Should be a map of Uganda)
[image]

GeoJSON snippet

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "D_06_ID": 1,
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [472470.4185696139, 183515.90337615015]
```

Code

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .scale(60)

var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

svg.selectAll(".subunit")
        .data(data.features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path);
```

Comment: Looks like your GeoJSON is faulty. Did you check that?

Comment: Thanks, I saved out the map as GeoJSON from a shp file I opened in QGIS. It looks good in QGIS ...

Comment: Many coordinates are in this range, does that look OK? [ 645190.187330584973097, 348889.999961694469675 ], [ 645425.687874804250896, 349803.000410544686019 ]. Given the mercator projection above ...

Comment: Well certainly doesn't look like Mercator coordinates to me. But the picture you're seeing isn't just a problem of that.

Comment: Your coordinates look like they're orders of magnitude off. So, the first set of coords should be [6.45..., 34.88...]. The next, [6.45..., 34.98...]. I've had this problem with QGIS as well - I've just multiplied/divided by 10,000... Quick google, and it looks like the central coords of Uganda are 1.0667° N, 31.8833° E.

Comment: @angela Thanks, seems to make sense. Can you do this inside QGIS?

Comment: Hm - I honestly don't remember, I think I just hacked it in Stata or Excel. :/ Kind of horrible, but there you go!